# How do pass arguments to subroutines in Perl/Tk?

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I have designed one sign-up form,in this form after getting all necessary values I will click submit button.

And while clicking that submit button I want to call one function and I want to pass the arguments to that function.

I have written code for this purpose,but the function is called first before getting the details.(i.e)after getting the details in sign-up form I need to pass these values to one function and I need to validate those values.

But what happened was,before getting the details the function get called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Carlos's suggestion is one way. Another is to put a command callback on the button that reads the values out of the form and calls your function, perhaps like this.

```
$button->configure(-command => sub { yourFunc($var1, $var2); });
```

I'm assuming you've bound the fields of the form to the variables `$var1` and `$var2` here; modify to fit your own situation of course.

Answer (score 3):

You have a number of options when specifying a code ref and arguments to a bind to a widget:

```
$w->configure( -command => [ \&subname,   @args ... ]             );
$w->configure( -command => [ sub { ... }, @args ... ]             );
$w->configure( -command => [ 'methodname', $invocant, @args ... ] );
$w->configure( -command => [ $invocant, 'methodname', @args ... ] );
```

See the [Tk::callbacks](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tk::callbacks) POD for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a vwait problem. Check in the Perl/Tk documentation for:

```
$widget->waitVariable(varRef)
```

In this way you are sure your code is only executed when the wait variable is modified (that's when you click the "submit" button)

Hope it helps.